# How to add padding to JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, padding, jcombobox, jtextfield

Imagine a `Panel` with an editable `JCombobox` and a `JTextfield` in vertical order.

The `Textfield` displays its content with a small padding to the left edge, the `Combobox` doesn't.

Does anybody know how I can add this padding to the `JCombobx`?

I've tried setting a renderer but the javadoc says:

> Sets the renderer that paints the list items and the item selected
>   from the list in
>   the JComboBox field. The renderer is used if the JComboBox is not
>   editable. If it is editable, the editor is used to render and edit
>   the selected item.

Best regards 
Marco

Comment: *"imagine"..*  I don't have much of an imagination, how about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, here is a Screenshot of the problem: http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/660/screenshotix.jpg

Comment: Tip  SSCCE!=screenshot.  Please ***read*** the content at the end of the link & stop guessing.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, setPrototypeDisplayValue may help you here, but really we need a screenshot of the problem and what you need to change.

Comment: no, the prototype has nothing to do with the details of the visual representation, it's only used to measure the (fixed) size needed for displaying an item.

Comment: Yes I imagine visual representation and displaying an item are completely different?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`JTextField#setMargin`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29) to get rid of the margin. Not exactly what you asked for, but hey, your components will be aligned.

Another solution is to use a `FlowLayout`, use the [`setHGap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#setHgap%28int%29) to manually set the distance between the border of the container and the components, and still use the [`JTextField#setMargin`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29) method to make sure the checkbox and textfield are aligned

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what LayoutManager you're using, if I understand you right.
In this sample: http://pastebin.com/PFr1jafP you will not see any padding you mentioned.

Try to provide small code sample / screen shot of what you're trying to achieve to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

very simple fix to render the space....

create a cell Renderer and add it to the combo box, adding in the space or just add

setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1)); o the cell renderer

either

```
@Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        JComponent comp = (JComponent) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, " "+value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        return comp;
    }
```

or

```
@Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        JComponent comp = (JComponent) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        comp.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        return comp;
    }
```

Comment: the second one is a better implementation